# Gcloud components on linux

Tags: gcloud

I ran the gcloud components update on ubuntu. After updating I received the following warning
WARNING:   There are other instances of Google Cloud Platform tools on your system PATH.
Please remove the following to avoid confusion or accidental invocation:

/usr/bin/gsutil
What will happen if I do not remove it?
How should I remove it

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. You may find the site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section and this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) checklist useful guidance for asking a good question. It is easier for people to help you if you include the code that you've worked on to solve the problem and ideally provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think that the SDK CLI was installed with one method and you are trying to update with another method. Your question does not include enough details on the system, history, etc. For example, the original package might have been installed with **snap** or with **apt-get**. If that is the case, then you will need to use that tool to update. Another option is to uninstall and then install with your preferred method. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install